# D3. Is it possible to recover the index of a datum associated with a selection?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In D3 I can access the datum associated with a selection (of one item in this instance) as follows:

```
var d = selection.datum();
```

Is it possible to access the index from the original data join as well? Or do I have to cache that myself, which would be messier.

Comment: Doesn't look like it. Checking the D3.js source code, it stores the data value in the `__data__` property of the node, but it doesn't save the index anywhere.

Comment: Don't all the update methods provide access to the index of the current selection? selection.attr("foo", function(d,i) { ... })? It's not exactly what you are looking for, but along with using the data key function and sort/order, it should be equivalent.

Comment: Yep, Lars's approach will work.